# Terraform: How to set the Amazon Athena "Query result location" with Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-athena

[image: 1]

Please assist me if anybody knows how to set Athena Query result location via Terraform

My code looks like below

```
resource "aws_athena_workgroup" "athena_query_result" {
 name = var.name
configuration {
  enforce_workgroup_configuration    = true
  publish_cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true

result_configuration {
  output_location = "s3://athena-query-location/output/"

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure it with `aws_athena_workgroup` resource

```
resource "aws_athena_workgroup" "example" {
  name = "example"

  configuration {
    enforce_workgroup_configuration    = true
    publish_cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true

    result_configuration {
      output_location = "s3://${aws_s3_bucket.example.bucket}/output/"

      encryption_configuration {
        encryption_option = "SSE_KMS"
        kms_key_arn       = aws_kms_key.example.arn
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried, but not working for me?

Comment: My example will create new workgroup, did you checked newly created workgroup or `primary` workgroup?

Comment: Ohh I checked the primary workgroup.

Is there any way to update the primary work group?

Comment: `primary` workgroup is created by default by AWS. if you want to configure it you need `import` it to terraform then you can configure it. 

`terraform import aws_athena_workgroup.example primary`